# How to find non-NA values (sample size) of a large data frame?

Tags: r, na, sample-size

I have a large data frame that contains lots of NAs. The rows are soil samples from different plots, and the columns are chemical variables. I wanted to create a column or data frame with the sample size of each variable to identify which variables may be undersampled.

When I tried looking online, there were answers that were specific to correlation tests and answers focused on finding number of occurrences of specific values, not just the presence of a non-NA vector, so that did not help me.

I can brute-force the issue by counting NAs in each column and subtracting those from the # of samples, but I have 400 columns and don't know how to write a function?

| Sample ID | C:N | %Fe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Plot1 | 46 | 3 |
| Plot2 | NA | 5 |

If this were the table, I'd want a column or data frame of "C:N sample size" = 1, %Fe = 2. This is where it's odd, because there would only be 1 row for each column variable, so I guess I'd want to make it as a new data frame or table.

If there's any links to good guides for making reprexes for data frames for R, I'd also appreciate that- this is my first question.

Thank you!

Comment: To count non-NA values in a vector you would do `sum(!is.na(x))` where `!` means not. To apply that function to all columns of a data frame `dat`, you would do `sapply(dat, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the `NA`s per column in `your_dataframe`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

your_dataframe %>% 
  map_df(~sum(is.na(.)))
```